# To Add the Expand collapse functionality in a .jsp to display and hide the data using <rich:dataTable> JSF component

Tags: jsf

Requirement:
To Add the Expand collapse functionality in a .jsp to display and hide the data using   JSF component.

Details:

Here I'm able to get the data from webservices to jsp. While displaying 
the data there is a provision to show and hide some of its data

Example:

If Suppose there are 3 rows(Student data) coming from database, Say each row as Student for instance. and Each student is associated with some courses(Say course1, course2 and course3).

Appearance should look like this:

Table1:

```
Details S.No    S.Name  S.Address
--------------------------------
+   10  Alex    Texas
+   20  John    Dallas
+   30  Nick    Newyork
```

Now if we click on + button associated with first record, it should exapand and show the first record details and - button to be displayed as shown below.

Table2:

```
Details S.No    S.Name  S.Address
--------------------------------
-   10  Alex    Texas

    course1 : Java
    cpurse2 : j2ee

-   20  John    Dallas

    course1: .Net
    course2: php

+   30  Nick    Newyork
```

And when when we click on - button it should hide the data and should display the above data as Table1.

Code I've used in Jsp page:

Here I got all the data dynamically. The only problem is UI arrangement(Displaying it). I've put the S.No, S.Name and S.Address fields in one  and course details in another . Both columnGroup are embedded in

Here I am facing a problem while displaying courses for each student(Means expand/collapse or show/hide). Facing problem to include a div or a subTable or something else in dataTable.

Request you to help me in this regard and let me know in case any details 
required from my end.

Sincerely,
Vamshi

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`<rich:subTable>`](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossrichfaces/freezone/docs/development/userguide/en/html/rich_subTable.html) which you toggle to show/hide with a shot of Javascript and CSS.